# Reset Parse User Password via Mailgun

Tags: ios, swift, mailgun, parse-server

I have setup a mailgun account and verified the domain, etc.  But how do I integrate this mailgun account into my Xcode 8/Swift 3 project?  I have read several threads that mention an index.js file but I don't know where/what this is.

I have the function below in my app and it is trying to execute:

```
PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmail(inBackground: emailToLowerCase) { (success, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            let success = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Success! Check your email!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            success.addAction(okButton)
            self.present(success, animated: false, completion: nil)

        }else {
            let errormessage = error
            let error = UIAlertController(title: "Cannot complete request", message: errormessage as! String, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            error.addAction(okButton)
            self.present(error, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

}
```

The block runs but error returns:

```
[Error]: An appName, publicServerURL, and emailAdapter are required for password reset functionality.
```

I know why I am getting the error (the mailgun is not integrated into my code), but I do not know how to fix after days of searching and reading through MANY, MANY stackoverflow threads.

I appreciate any help offered!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue ?